# How can I use LI and CSS to display these movies

Tags: html, css, list, inline

I've been designing a template but when I come to the part where I need to display some movies using `li` items it does not work... You see I want to display a thumbnail then the name of the movie and then the season and eps.

I was thinking about `UL` and `LI` but looks like I can not get it to work... If some of you know how to do it using HTML and CSS please let me know.

Comment: I've tried this <li><img src="imgpath"><a href="#" title="mtitle"></a><a href="#" class="mname"></a> and <a href="#" class="mseasons"></a></li>

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `<ul><li>` in combination with a `<figure>` element. Example:

```
<li>
    <figure>
        <img src="...">
        <figcaption>Description Here</figcaption>
    </figure>
</li>
```

And so forth.

As for CSS, float them to the left, clear every third element.